# How can I 'if' condition in docment.getElementById.style.background?

Tags: if-statement, colors, background, document

```
.div_wrap_p_bestgames {
    display: table;
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: #1B1C1E;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

this is css code.
I want to set div_wrap_p_bestgames's mouseout function
if condition with background color #1B1C1E

```
function onMouseoutNewGames() {
        if (document.getElementById("div_wrap_p_newgames").style.background == "#1B1C1E")
        ///do something
}
```

this condition is not working

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the below line to get the background color of an element

`document.getElementById("div_wrap_p_newgames").style.backgroundColor`

if you need to compare this with a specific value, convert your hex code to a rgb value and compare it as such,

`if(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(27, 28, 30)")`

rgb(28,27,30) is the equivalent of #1B1C1E

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <div id="myDiv" style="background-color:#1B1C1E;">This is a div element.</div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Get the background color of div</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            if(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor == "rgb(27, 28, 30)")
            {
                alert("hi");
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Works fine when I try it.